# And he shall rend it by its wings - questions on the burnt offering

Tags: commentaries, korban, birds, parashat-vayikra

Today, my Chavrusa and I were learning Parashas [(Vayikra 1:17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.1.16?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> And if the burnt sacrifice for his offering to the Lord be of birds, then he shall bring his offering of turtledoves, or of young pigeons.
> And the priest shall bring it to the altar, and wring off its head, and burn it on the altar; and its blood shall be wrung out at the side of the altar:
> and he shall remove its crop with its feathers, and cast it beside the altar on the east part, by the place of the ashes:
> and he shall rend it by its wings, but shall not divide it asunder: and the priest shall burn it on the altar, on the wood that is on the fire: it is a burnt sacrifice, an offering made by fire, of a sweet savour to the Lord.

When reading pasuk 16-17, the following question occured and I was not able to locate any meforshim that adresses this same question:

1. The Torah states ["and he shall rend it by its wings"](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.1.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). He shall not completely detach the feathers (according to the opinion of the [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.1.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en)) and according to [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=2492708&jewish=Vayikra-Torah-Reading.htm&p=2), "he shall split it open with its wing feathers [intact], but he shall not tear it completely apart". It would be much easier to just detach the feathers, but the Torah explicitly instructs us not to. **Why "he shall rend"?**

**What is the deeper meaning/lesson the Torah is teaching us here?**

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.1.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.1.17.3&ven2=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&vhe2=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang2=bi

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of this Rashi, however, the question is, why is it forbidden to break it into two pieces as Rashi writes "he must not break it entirely into two piece". Breaking it into two pieces seems to be much easier than "to rend it from behind".

Comment: Same reason, so it looks bigger.

Comment: Ah okay, that seems to be the peshat though. Any idea if there excists a deeper meaning, a spiritual meaning given by the mefarshim?

Comment: The meaning cited by Rashi of sensitivity to people's feelings seems very deep to me, but there are always more layers.